# Can i place native dependencies in a subfolder

Tags: .net-core, publish

When i publish a dotnet core project, it generated a single folder with hundreds of framework and native runtime files in it.

I understand that these files are required to make everything work, but can i move them into a subfolder and still get my app to run?

For example

```
MYAppFolder\
    MyApp.exe
    MyApp.exe.config
    native\
       hostfxr.dll
       netstandard.dll
       ...
```

Is there some sort of probing path configuration that can do this?

Comment: I think the only way this could work, is if you modify the `%path%` .NET is finicky about on how it looks for native DLLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can see you have a `Standalone (SCD)` app.

For that type of deployment `hostfxr.dll` should always exist in the app directory by convention.

As to other deps, you are able to move them to any locations, however you'll need to edit `[AppName].deps.json` for every build and also specify *Additional probing paths*. Besides, you are free to remove all the redundant dependencies (from deps.json and the file itself) if you are sure that you don't use them.

Check [this demo](https://github.com/izaruba/StandaloneNetCoreAppSubFolder) where I've put all the dependencies of a `Standalone` app that could be moved to other location to a `lib` subdirectory.

please, note the following:

- Additional probing path is set in [HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.json](https://github.com/izaruba/StandaloneNetCoreAppSubFolder/blob/master/HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.json#L4) but you can also use *--additionalprobingpath [path]* argument or Environment varibable
- I've removed relative paths in deps.json file because otherwise I would have put the files to those relative paths sub directories - *Additional probing path* is considered to be a `NuGet package cache` thus have a package layout inside.

Also, consider having a `Portable (FDD)` type. You'll have a much less footprint and more flexibility arranging the files.

Comment: Well, I managed to eliminate the paths of each dll and exe in the deps.json file with a regex replace of `@"(?<="").*[/|\\](?=.*dll|.*exe)"`, however this does still not work.  Even with the additionalProbingPath in the runtimeconfig and the flattened paths it even whines: `An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (xxxxx.deps.json) was not found`. Even when I use an absolute file path to the given assembly.

Comment: @Waescher can you share the code? What version of .NET Core SDK do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It's a netcoreapp2.1. I prepared a sample, just clone https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ, checkout the branch `AdditionalProbingPath` and run the cake build in PowerShell `.\build.ps1 -Target Publish`. This will throw out two executables `grr.exe` and `grrui.exe` in `_output/win/Assemblies`. Both of them won't run in a command line because of missing dependencies like AsyncIO.dll.

Comment: @Waescher The problem is that `additionalProbingPath` option is considered to be a NuGet package cache. `AsyncIO` is considered to be a package, thus it is by default searched in `AsyncIO/0.1.26/AsyncIO.dll` unless `"path"` value is overridden in `"libraries"` section of `grr.deps.json`. I suggest you enable Trace Mode (set COREHOST_TRACE=1) hence you will understand what's wrong. To fix your issue, set `"path": "/"` to the libraries you need to be loaded from `lib` folder (https://github.com/izaruba/StandaloneNetCoreAppSubFolder/blob/master/HelloWorld.deps.json#L338).

Comment: Also, put `/` in fron of `clrjit.dll` and `coreclr.dll` https://github.com/izaruba/StandaloneNetCoreAppSubFolder/blob/master/HelloWorld.deps.json#L250-L251

Comment: Holy ... good spot, I was removing the paths to the dlls on lines like this: https://github.com/izaruba/StandaloneNetCoreAppSubFolder/blob/40dc305ec110db972c26cdeec2f69ada560fd0be/HelloWorld.deps.json#L15  In my case, there were some folders in that line (not in your sample). Is this required as well? I'll try that later, thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually you could modify an entry in `targets` section like this `"../../AsyncIO/0.1.26": { ... }`, I think this would work yet look ugly. Modifying `path` is much better.

Comment: OMG, I just cannot figure out what the problem is. It has been a very long time that I have been so frustrated and felt like a poor schoolboy after all these years of great development joy. I really love technical challenges. It's my job and my hobby - but this is really, really annoying. Man, I am happy that you want to help me but this is just plain ugly stuff. Poking around strange paths in undocumented targets/libraries ... I even really wonder myself how painful this seems to me.

Comment: Would you mind to continue this stuff on GitHub? I wrote an issue for that: https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ/issues/55

Comment: made a PR. Please, let me know if that is what you need