# additionalProbingPaths not respected after dotnet publish?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I'm using dotnet 2.1.4 on Windows. dotnet --info shows:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  5e8add2190

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.5
  Build    : 17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54
```

I'm using dotnet publish to create the output for a platform:

```
dotnet publish ..\src\ChestnutDS.Host\ChestnutDS.Host.csproj
     -c Release -o ..\..\published\win-x64
     --self-contained -r win-x64 -v n
```

This gives me the desired (and working) output in a folder with 323 files.

[image: published folder]

Now, what I want to do is move all most of the files into a subfolder, e.g., lib.

[image: Moved most of the stuff into lib]

From what I've gathered, setting `additionalProbingPaths` in the runtimeconfig.json [**should** work:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839958/can-i-place-native-dependencies-in-a-subfolder/47867045#47867045)

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
      "lib"
    ]
  }
}
```

But it complains about not finding the libraries:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (ChestnutDS.Host.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
```

Trying to pass --additionalProbingPath as a command line argument also doesn't work, same error.

Trying to create the mentioned structure and moving the file (`lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll`) also doesn't work.

Am I missing something? Was that functionality removed? It doesn't seem like it, the [source code still contains it](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/5a1a53181b51c00b34c9b2fb8be92d6f03b5e9ed/src/corehost/cli/runtime_config.cpp#L77).

Comment: Looking into this some more, I see that I also need to make changes in the `.deps.json` file, but I haven't found the correct combination of settings to make this work yet.

Comment: `what I want to do is move all most of the files into a subfolder` - Which is it? All or most?

Comment: @NightOwl888 All that I can, apart from the executable the person runs and some data files (config.json, database.xml in the above example). And apart from that, only what I absolutely need. Everything else should go into the subfolder.

Comment: @MichaelStum, did you get any further with this?

Comment: @MichaelStum, did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to create the mentioned structure and moving the file

Looks like you have `lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll` in `targets/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/2.0.1/runtime` and `"path": "microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery/2.0.1"` in `libraies/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/2.0.1` entry. In that case the expected structure would be `<additional probing path>/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/2.0.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll`

There are two types of source folders, where `hostpolicy.dll` is searching for dependent libraries (`*.dll` or `*.ni.dll`):

- regular folder (files exist in the folder's root, "path" is omitted)
- NuGet cache (has a specific subfolders structure for each dependency entry `<PackageName>/<Version>/<DllPath>` and by default `*.deps.json` is generated to satisfy this convention)

Dependencies are searched in these folders:

- App folder (regular folder) - the folder, where App.exe (App.dll) has been executed; default for SCD.
- Framework folder (regular folder) - **only for Framework Dependent Deployment**, e.g. `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.4\`.
- Probing Paths (NuGet cache).

Suppose we had this `App.deps.json` (self-contained deployment)

```
"targets": {
    "runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0": {
        "runtime": {
              "foo/Microsoft.CSharp.dll": {},  // <========
        }
    }
}

"libraries": {
    "runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0": {
      "type": "package",
      "serviceable": true,
      "sha512": "sha512-8jivXDJLuJTxMQuInZaMiD2VbxehFmYAtn2V9mj9juaR5jH54/OBGmGv6SrIUVNqASXB/8dJbce/beIKnOzroQ==",
      "path": "bar", // <========
      "hashPath": "runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app.2.0.0.nupkg.sha512"
    }
}
```

First of all, `hostpolicy.dll` will create a list of all assets - libraries from "runtime" and "native" properties of each dependency package.

Next, it has to create a TPA (Trusted Platform Assemblies) list with the absolute path of each asset. To do that, it will first search in the app folder `<app folder path>\Microsoft.CSharp.dll` (**note**, that it will omit "path" for this particular folder).

Once the DLL was not found, it will examine `Additional Probing Paths` if any.

This time, since `Additional Probing Path` is considered to be a NuGet cache, it expects a certain subfolders structure to exist.
Specifically, it will take `Package Name` and `Version` from `"libraries"` section, combine `"path"` and DLL path from `"runtime"` (or `"native"`) section.

Thus, for `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` the probing path would be `<Additional Probing Path>/bar/foo/Microsoft.CSharp.dll`